# Bordes redondos y cuadrados

Tags: java, netbeans-8.1

La interfaz de la izquierda lo hice con NetBeans (use el JFrame Form); el de la derecha lo hice en el Bloc de Notas. El problema es que no se coml hacer que los bordes, tanto del JButton como de los JCombo Box sean cuadrados, como en la imagen debla derecha
[Izquierna Netbeans, Derecha con Bloc de Notas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9VEf.png)

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Te recomiendo que sigas el [tour] para poder reformular tu pregunta y que esta sea contestada. Te adelando que necesitarás mostrar algo de codigo escrito

Comment: Cuando edites la pregunta para añadir más información, no olvides el `initComponents()` de ambos programas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo nunca había notado la diferencia, debido a que no suelo utilizar el editor de NetBeans, pero es verdad que existe una diferencia.
Para realizar dicho cambio de los objetos en general tienes que borrar un conjunto de lineas que siempre están contraídas y parece que son un comentario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que si despliegas la pestaña con el "+" se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese código hace que cambie la apariencia de los componentes.

Solo lo eliminas ya sea la linea contraída o todas las lineas dentro del signo "+".
y Listo tendrás componentes nativos.

Saludos